# How to get the actual measurement value from measurement chracteristic UUID: 2A9D of AND BLE WS in an iOS app using SWIFT 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to synchronize the actual measurement value from measurement characteristic UUID of AND BLE weight scale model no: A&D_UC-352BLE_011E17 in an iOS app using swift. The app is reading the measurement characteristic UUID and 10 bytes value from the BLE WS, but when it is trying to read the actual measurement value from NSData it is synchronizing and showing a wrong value in the app, for example for actual weight 59.2 KG the app is getting a value of 11860.0.

I have implemented all the related methods required for pairing and synchronizing the data from this BLE WS, most probably the app is also getting the weight scale measurement service UUID: 181D and measurement characteristic UUID: 2A9D from BLE WS, because I have seen these values in Xcode debug console.

In that case I think the main problem is in reading/converting the measurement characteristic UUID value to actual measurement value of type double. My didUpdateCharacteristicValue  method is given below, please suggest me how I can get the actual measurement value from measurement characteristic UUID?

```
func didUpdateCharacteristicValue(_ characteristic: CBCharacteristic){
communicating = true

    let charUUID = ANDWeightScaleBTManager.measurementWeightCharacteristicUUID

    print("did update value for characteristic")

    print("charUUID:", charUUID)

    print("charValue is", characteristic.value!)

    print("value is:" + (characteristic.value?.base64EncodedString())!)

    if (charUUID == ANDWeightScaleBTManager.measurementWeightCharacteristicUUID) 

    {
        NSLog("Got Weight Scale Measurement char")

        var weightData: NSData

        weightData = characteristic.value! as NSData

        //var data: NSData

        //weightData = NSData.init(data: characteristic.value!)//if (bpmData.length <= 12) {

        let flag = weightData.subdata(with: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: 1))

        let unit : UInt16 = readInteger(data: weightData, start: 0)

        let weight : UInt16 = readInteger(data: weightData, start: 1)

        print("weight: \(weight)")//print the output

        var message: String

        var image: UIImage

        var data = [MeasurementType: Double]()

        message = "Completed measurement."

        image = UIImage(named: "Success")!

        data = [.weight: Double(weight)]

        shouldEnd = true

        update(data, message, image, shouldEnd)

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the [documentation for the characteristic](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.weight_measurement.xml) you will see that a metric (SI) value is in units of 0.005kg.

If you multiply the value you have, 11860, by 0.005 you get 59.3kg.

```
let kg = Double(weight) * 0.005
```

Comment: That works for me, Thanks a lot for your suggestion.